# Detecting forms (and filling them in) with Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, lxml

I'm struggling to find a generic approach to detecting a form in HTML and then submitting it. When the page structure is know *in advance* for a given page, we of course have several options:

-- Selenium/Webdriver (by filling in the fields and 'clicking' the button)

-- Determining the form of the POST query manually, then reconstructing it with **urllib2** directly:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import lxml.html as LH

url = "http://apply.ovoenergycareers.co.uk/vacancies/#results"
params = urllib.urlencode([('field_36[]', 73), ('field_37[]', 76),   
('field_32[]', 82)])
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, params)
```

or with **Requests**:

```
import requests
r = requests.post("http://apply.ovoenergycareers.co.uk/vacancies/#results", data = 'Manager')
r.text
```

But although most forms involve a POST request, some input fields and a submit button, they vary greatly in their implementation under the hood. When the number of pages to be scraped gets into the hundreds, it's not feasible to define a custom form-filling approach for each.

My understanding is that **Scrapy**'s main added value is its ability to follow links. I presume that this would also include links ultimately arrived at via form submission. Can this ability then be used to build a generic approach to "following" a form submission?

**CLARIFICATION:** In the case of a form with several dropdown menus, I will typically be leaving these at their default value, and only filling in the search term input field. So locating this field and 'filling it in' is ultimately the main challenge here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link Extractors cannot follow the form submissions in Scrapy. There is an another mechanism called [`FormRequest`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects) that is specifically designed to ease submitting forms.

Note that `FormRequest`s cannot handle forms when JavaScript is involved in the submission.

Comment: I wasn't aware that `lxml` had form-detecting and form-submitting capabilities. I think what I will need to do is for every form I encounter, use `lxml.html.submit_form()` to submit the form with all fields left blank, and then scrape the resulting page for the keyword, rather than trying to determine which field in the form is the keyword field.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into Selenium with PhantomJS. It can handle JS and then you can use the CSS selectors from Selenium to pick specific elements on the webpage.

Comment: Thanks. But whether PhantomJS or a regular browser is used with Selenium, the program will still require knowledge (XPath / CSS) of page elements.

Comment: Yes. It would still require knowledge of exact CSS elements.